# Group text range in MS Word with JavaScript API

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I want to group a text range in MS Word. I have access to the [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview) object but I can't find an API method to group it.

On MS Word, it is possible to do it using this option:
[image]

Is it possible to do so using JS API method for Word add-in?

Answer (score 1):

Grouping is not supported in the Word JavaScript library. But its a good idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: I did as you said. Can you please upvote my idea there? Here is the link: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/40707418-javascript-api-to-group-a-range-of-text